# VSCode - Haskell - Go to definition - no definition found?

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code, haskell-language-server

I installed Haskell tools, ghc and ghci, Haskell Language Server with [ghcup](https://www.haskell.org/ghcup/).
I also have VSCode [Haskell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=haskell.haskell) installed.

How can I get VSCode to navigate me to a function definition? With current setup it returns no definition found.

Comment: I don't think there is enough info in your post to diagnose the problem. Here are a bunch of questions: Can you give some example code? Does it say no definition found for all symbols or just for some specific ones? Which version of GHC are you using? Does the Haskell extension work at all, e.g. does it highlight errors?

Comment: Also you can see a debug log by going to View->Output and then in the panel that opens there is a dropdown menu in the top-right, one of the options should be "Haskell". Can you post the contents of that log?